# Extract attributes from innerHtml

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have the following WebElement. How can I extract the latitude and longitude?

```
       <span class="geotag" xmlns:geo="//www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
        (<geo:lat>40.75198</geo:lat>,<geo:long>-73.96978</geo:long>)
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be the following:

```js
const tag = document.querySelector(".geotag")

let latitude
let longitude
if (tag.children[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === "geo:lat") {
  latitude = tag.children[0].innerText
  longitude = tag.children[1].innerText
} else {
  latitude = tag.children[1].innerText
  longitude = tag.children[0].innerText
}

console.log(latitude, longitude)
```

```html
<span class="geotag" xmlns:geo="//www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
  (<geo:lat>40.75198</geo:lat>,<geo:long>-73.96978</geo:long>)
</span>
```

You select the element, then check which of the children is the latitude and which is the longitude. Then set the variables accordingly.

Of course, the selection of the element could be made easier, if it had a unique ID instead of only a class.

Comment: How would I do this using python?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code with explanation:

```
# Below line will store the desired element text
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='geotag']"))).text
# Below 2 lines will strip the open and closed braces
element = element.rstrip(')')
element = element.lstrip('(')
# Below line will split the string by ','
split = element.split(',')
# Store first index of array
latitude = split[0]
# Store second index of array
longitude= split[1]
# Print
print("latitude = " + latitude)
print("longitude= " + longitude)
```

Console output:

```
latitude = 40.75198
longitude= -73.96978
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a `:` in the tag name, add a backslash (`\`) before the `:` for the selector:

```py
latitude = driver.find_element("css selector", "span.geotag geo\:lat").text

longitude = driver.find_element("css selector", "span.geotag geo\:long").text
```

Results:

```
(Pdb+) latitude
'40.75198'
(Pdb+) longitude
'-73.96978'
```

Comment: This is not working for me in python3